# How to add integers in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calculated-columns

I am new to rails app, and I had the users input 3 different integers. How do I add up the sum of the integers stored in the database and show the sum. Assuming I have these integers :dish1 (3), :dish2 (2), :dish3 (5) the sum should show 10? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what fields are in which models/if the dishes are a has_many association?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your table schema, and assuming you are using ActiveRecord, here is a sample code.

```
  record = Model.first
  sum_of_dishes = record.dish1.to_i + record.dish2.to_i + record.dish3.to_i
```